# php / codeigniter redirect user based on group membership

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this login php file from a CodeIgniter based PHP app. Basically I want to edit this so that if the user is member of "salesman" group then redirect them to another page. This will just be for this group others will redirect as normal and wont be effected.

Presume I need to add in an If at some part.

```
class Auth extends MX_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('ion_auth');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    // Load MongoDB library instead of native db driver if required
    $this->config->item('use_mongodb', 'ion_auth') ?
        $this->load->library('mongo_db') :
        $this->load->database();

}

//redirect if needed, otherwise display the user list
function index()
{
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        redirect('module=auth&view=login');
    } else {
        redirect('module=home');
    }
}

function users() {
    $groups = array('admin', 'purchaser', 'salesman', 'viewer');
    if ($this->ion_auth->in_group($groups))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->lang->line("access_denied"));
        $data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message'));
        redirect('module=home', 'refresh');
    }

    $this->user_check();

    $data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');
    $data['success_message'] = $this->session->flashdata('success_message');

        //list the users
        $data['users'] = $this->ion_auth->users()->result();
        foreach ($data['users'] as $k => $user)
        {
            $data['users'][$k]->groups = $this->ion_auth->get_users_groups($user->id)->result();
        }

        $meta['page_title'] = 'Users';
        $this->load->view('commons/header', $meta);

        $this->load->view('index', $data);

        $this->load->view('commons/footer');
}
//log the user in
function login()
{
    $data['title'] = "Login";

    //validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('identity', 'Identity', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
    { //check to see if the user is logging in
        //check for "remember me"
        $remember = (bool) $this->input->post('remember');

        if ($this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('identity'), $this->input->post('password'), $remember))
        { //if the login is successful
            //redirect them back to the home page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success_message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
            redirect('module=home', 'refresh');
        }
        else
        { //if the login was un-successful
            //redirect them back to the login page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
            redirect('module=auth&view=login', 'refresh'); //use redirects instead of loading views for compatibility with MY_Controller libraries
        }
    }
    else
    {  //the user is not logging in so display the login page
        //set the flash data error message if there is one
        $data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');
        $data['success_message'] = $this->session->flashdata('success_message');
        $data['identity'] = array('name' => 'identity',
            'id' => 'identity',
            'type' => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('identity'),
        );
        $data['password'] = array('name' => 'password',
            'id' => 'password',
            'type' => 'password',
        );

        $this->load->view('auth/login', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition will catch the logged in user's group and, if they are `salesman`, redirect them to `to/whatever/page`.

```
   if ($this->ion_auth->in_group(array('salesman')))
     redirect('to/whatever/page');
   }
```

Comment: Total noob, where about should I add this in? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: not exactly sure from which method you want to redirect from.. but I am guessing it's as soon as they land on the page... in which case add it inside the `index()` method, just above `redirect('module=auth&view=login');`

Comment: So the user puts their name and password in and then that's when the redirect would occur rather than when they land on the page. I have a login page which calls this auth.php to determine how to log them in. Again thanks for your help, its really appreciated.

Comment: put it above `redirect('module=home', 'refresh');` in `login()` method